# What part of speech would "color" be in, "Mercury is the color red"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, parts-of-speech

> Mercury is red.
>
> Mercury is the color red.

*Red* is describing Mercury. What part of speech would *color* be?

Comment: Red is describing the color of Mercury. Mercury's color. Color is a noun.

Comment: Are you asking which part of speech is _color_, or _red_?

Comment: The final sentence "What part of speech would color be?" seems to be pretty clear. I am editing the question to add quotes though.

Comment: @slim I was wondering how the question got an apparently wrong answer.

Comment: @NNZ Did you look at what a dictionary reports for _color_? What part eventually didn't you understand?

Comment: Harsh to close it I think. By inference, the question is "I know 'color' is a noun, but here it is where an adjective should be, what's going on?"

Comment: Why was this question closed? I don't think a single one of the four answers is correct. (Certainly none of them were upvoted.) I agree with @slim ... it's an interesting grammar question.

Comment: I do not accept OP's second sentence as valid English. It sounds ungrammatical to me, and I couldn't find any written instances of such usage in [Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q="is%20the%20colour%20red"&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en). If it *were* to be analysed as a valid construction, obviously both "colour" and "red" are functioning as nouns. But what is the point of analysing such a contrived sentence?

Comment: I don't agree with closing the question. A Google search for ["grass is the color green"](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22grass+is+the+color+green%22)and a Google book search for ["sky is the color blue"](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22sky+is+the+color+blue%22#q=%22sky+is+the+color+blue%22&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=bks&source=og&sa=N&tab=wp&ei=Au_vTtOGLdHyggfF7sGVCQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=30aed10b55343040&biw=1066&bih=582) show that this construction is definitely in use.

Comment: Furthermore, it has an answer: "colour" and "red" are both nouns in apposition. See [Apposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) in wikipedia.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you think that the OP meant "Mercury is red _in_ colour"? That would be both clear and grammatically correct in my opinion.

Comment: @BoldBen: I'm sure that's what OP meant. My point was that it's non-idiomatic to say *Mercury is the colour red*. But I'd certainly accept more straightforward "copula" constructions such as *Mercury is the metal hydrargyrum, Cerise is the colour red, N1 is the X N2* - effectively meaning *N1 is another name for N2, which is an X* (so by implication N1 is *also* an X, because N1 and N2 are the same thing).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree completely, there just seemed to be a lot of thrashing about in the comments and answers trying to say "Mercury is red in colour' or 'Mercury is coloured red' in complex and unclear ways!

Answer (score 2):

It's an odd sentence, which may not be strictly grammatical. However I would probably not find it jarring if I heard or read it, so it may be a common idiom.

"*noun* is *noun*" sentences usually denote equality or set membership. "Obama is the president", "Rover is a dog", for example.

By that logic, the sentence is not true. "Mercury" is *not* "the colour red".

"Mercury is red" is a "*noun* is *adjective*" sentence. "David is hungry", "Madelyn is pretty".

The "the colour" part of the sentence could be seen as a clarifying clause: let us imagine that the adjective "red" is ambiguous. Perhaps the reader might think it means "communist". Perhaps we are speaking aloud and the listener might hear "Mercury is read".

So, we clarify by adding a clause saying "the colour".

- "Mercury is red -- by which I mean the colour red."
- "Mercury is red (the colour)"
- "Mercury is the colour red"

Another way to look at this is to view "the colour red" as an *adjectival phrase*.

In "John is fond of animals", "fond of animals" is an adjectival phrase. "Fond" is the adjective and "of animals" is a clarification of the adjective.

In "Mercury is the colour red", "the colour red" is an adjectival phrase. "Red" is the adjective and "the colour" is a clarification of the adjective.

In all these forms "colour" is a **noun**, even though red is an adjective. The final form may be ungrammatical, but likely to be found acceptable in all but the most formal settings.

Answer (score 0):

*Red* can be both an adjective and a noun. All color words in English function this way.

As an adjective:

> Mercury is a red metal.
>
> The mercury solution is red.

As a noun:

> Red is my favorite color.

Comment: The OP asked about the word "color", not "red".

Comment: Yes, but the question is, what part of speech is the word "colour" in that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

*Mercury is the colour red* asserts that the two concepts are the same, which is clearly wrong, and only just avoids being nonsense.  *Mercury is coloured red* may be what you are looking for, in which *coloured* is part of an adjectival phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on **which** *color* you are referring to. The word *color* is used in the different sentences as different parts of speech.

The word *color* can be used both as a noun as well as an adjective.

'Mercury is the color red' should properly be one of the following:

> Mercury's color is red.
>   Mercury is of the color red.
>   Mercury is red colored.
>   Mercury is colored red.